# Onsen UI with PhoneGap controllers load up in wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I am really new to the whole phonegap and onsen UI framework (and for web development, actually), but I tried following tutorials and asking around to get my mobile app working.

My problem is, that the homepage is reloaded twice before the app becomes usable. It's because it gets loaded upon startup, but only after it's loaded it runs the Login check, and then that reloads it.

So basically, if I debug in my browser, the appController.js file is running first (and then going through it a couple of times, from the start, like it's reloading or something), which is the controller for the homepage.html and basically all the pages (except login.html, which has loginController.js), and the main.js which has the checkLogin() function is only taken care of afterwards.

How can I specify, that the CheckLogin() function should be the first thing running when the application loads up?

Synchronizing them is my number one problem, and quite frankly i'm lost in the code.

Here are some sketches of my javascript files, as well as the index.html file

**main.js**

```
ons.ready(function() {
    checkLogin(storage.getItem("username"),storage.getItem("password"));
});

function checkLogin(username, password) {
    if(correctlogin) {
         menu.setMainPage('homepage.html');
    }
    else {
         menu.setMainPage('login.html');
    }
}

var myApp = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-csp>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/date.js"></script>
  <!-- Angular Controllers -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="loginController.js"></script>
  <script src="appController.js"></script>

  <!--JS-->
  <!--<script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jqm/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
  <script id="mobile-datepicker" src="js/jqm/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>

  <ons-sliding-menu main-page="homepage.html" menu-page="menu.html" side="right" max-slide-distance="250px" var="menu">
  </ons-sliding-menu>

  <ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item onclick="menu.setMainPage('navigator.html', {closeMenu: true})"> Home </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item onclick="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})"> Page1 </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="navigator.html">
    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="homepage.html">    
    </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>    

<ons-template id="homepage.html">
    <ons-page id="homepage" ng-controller="AppController">
        <ons-toolbar style="background-color:#222;">
            <div class="right">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="fa-bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center" style="color: white">Welcome my App</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <div style="width:80%; margin:0 auto;">
            <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('Settings.html', {closeMenu: true})" > Settings</ons-button>
        </div>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
</html>

<ons-template id="Page1.html">
   <ons-page id="Page1" ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="loadPage1()">
       <span>This is Page1 with AppController loaded to it</span>
       <span>{{Page1Variable}}</span>
   </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

The **login.html** has the loginController attached to it, but when there are saved credentials, it never gets loaded. (which is fine, I guess)

**appController.js**

```
myApp.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $timeout, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.loadPage1 = function() {
        $scope.Page1Variable = "HELLO WORLD";
    }

    $scope.loadSettingsVariables = function() {
        $scope.NotificationSettings = true;
    }
    ....
    other logic and actions...
}
```

When I hit refresh on the page, all the $scope.*function_name* lines are getting hit by the breakpoints, goes through the file, and only after that, the main.js file is called. And then it runs through again the AppController...

What am I doing wrong in terms of chaining them together.

I want a centralized function that would either put the user to the homepage.html or the login.html.

Also, did the **sliding-menu** made this happen? Or is it actually structured correctly?

NOTE: I am using both the sliding-menu and the navigator for navigation. Could that be the problem? (The navigator is handy, when i have to pop pages, when the page structure is multi-level)

NOTE2: On a different note, which **could** be related, I started to get the "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined*" error in jquery.mobile-1-4-5.min.js:4

Comment: It appears you are using Onsen 1.  If you are starting new, you really should try using Onsen 2.0 - much better with numerous features.  As far as you issue, your UI design / logic, imo, is slightly backwards.  Use the navigator as your main component with an ons-splitter in your home page.  Realistically though, why do you need both as the splitter component (sliding menu) basically acts as a navigator unless you are trying to hide your menu at some point?

Comment: Look at the options:  https://onsen.io/v2/  - Onsen 2.0  http://community.onsen.io  - Community Forums with lots of information  http://tutorial.onsen.io/ - Tutorials for Onsen 2.0

Comment: Tutorial for exactly what you are trying to do:  http://tutorial.onsen.io/?framework=vanilla&category=Community%20tutorials&module=splitter_navigator